# How to create a String[] array from a String?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a String on the variable *coords* which has the value of a String array, but it is not an array (outcome of toString).

```
String coords = "[[126,224],[255,232],[270,332],[106,444]]";
```

**How can you create a String array from this String?**
An array doesn't have a #valueOf (as far as I know) and you can't easily split the characters.

**Edit:** I am looking for a String array which contains the four Strings as their own entries. E.g. "126,224", "255,322"..

Comment: `String#split(String)`?

Comment: May I ask why you are instantiating it as a String if you wish to immediately convert to String[] ?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin You have to give a regex.

Comment: @ScottStainton In the code, I don't actually initiate the String, it is gained from a third-party library which returns a String object.

Comment: What should the array look like?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin The array should have the four Strings. E.g. "126,224" and "255,232".

Comment: Without complex regexes, replace all `[[` and `]]` with an empty character and then split by `],[`.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin You have an answer to submit :)

Comment: The string you have is basically JSON. It should be trivial to create the array with a json parser.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider My bad, didn't notice.

Comment: If you are willing to use external libraries, Jackson can do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to achieve that is:

```java
String[] array = coords.replaceAll("\\[\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]\\]", "").split("\\],\\[");
```

The above code replaces all `[[` and `]]` with an empty character and then split by `],[`.

Answer (score 2):

Solution with Stream API and without replacing

```
Arrays.asList(coords.split("\\[\\[|]]|],\\[")).stream().filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

or in commont case

```
Arrays.asList(coords.split("\\[\\[|]]|],\\[")).stream()
    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).forEach(s -> {
    //do whatever you want
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking for something like this?

```
public class Tmp {
    public static void test() {
        String coords = "[[126,224],[255,232],[270,332],[106,444]]";
        String arr[];
        if (coords.length() < 4) {
            arr = null;
        } else {
            arr = coords.substring(2, coords.length() - 2).split("\\],\\[");
        }
        for (String str : arr) {
            System.out.printf("%s\n", str);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test();
    }
}
```