# How create string array from single string in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, string, kotlin, split

I have a string line from EditText, all words separated from each other by comma just like this:

> "Some, string, words, bla-bla"

And I need to create array from this string, each element would be separate:

> "Some", "string", "words", "bla-bla"

So, I saw how it was done on Java [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37363627/how-to-create-a-string-array-from-a-string) but idk how convert it to kotlin, as I know Kotlin doesn't have *split* operator

This array I will save in preferences by putStringSet and use in another activity

Comment: ...[Kotlin does have split](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html)

Comment: can you help me how to use it in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kotlin has a split function too. It will return a `List<String>`. If you you need an array in the end, call `toTypedArray()`:

```
val strArray: Array<String> = "Some, string, words, bla-bla".split(", ").toTypedArray()
```